# SuiteScript 2.0 addButton should call a function?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

Say I have the following snippet, which is basically a form with a button attached to it. On click, I want to execute a function:

```
define(['N/ui/serverWidget', 'N/search', 'N/https'],
function(serverWidget, search, https) {
function onRequest(context) {
  if (context.request.method === 'GET') 
  {
    var form = serverWidget.createForm({
      title: 'Some Form'
    });
    // some code
    form.addButton({
      id : '_buttonId',
      label : 'Button Label',
      functionName: "someFunctinonIWantToCallOnClick(myParam)"
    });
      context.response.writePage(form)
    } else {
      // some other code
    }
  }
function someFunctinonIWantToCallOnClick(myParam)
{
  // some code
}
return {
  onRequest: onRequest
};
});
```

According to the NetSuite's documentation:

`options.functionName
string
optional`

The function name to be triggered on a click event.
Version 2016 Release 1

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of things wrong with your example.

1. you are not actually writing the form. Eventually you need:

   context.response.writePage(form);
2. Your function you want to call is only on the server. It is not defined on the client. You need to include a client script that has that function:

   form.clientScriptModulePath = './myFormClient.js';

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. 1. context.response.writePage(form); is there, right before the else statement. 2. That makes sense, so if I understood correctly: I need to move the someFunctinonIWantToCallOnClick(myParams) to a client script, bind it to the form and then my button will call the function?